# Loading template structure from an API and having it render normally

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

My question is a little obscure and i've tried a bunch of different options before resorting here.

I've had an iOS app for about 10 years, that I no longer wish to upkeep with native code, so I'm trying to make the switch to Ionic 2 since I know web better.

Anyway, my iOS app loads a bunch of content from a private API, and displays them in a table, upon selection it loads remote HTML into a UIWebView in the app.

Any links in the HTML are handled by iOS and when clicked are pushed onto the navigation stack in a new UIWebView.

That being said, I have my Ionic app connecting to my API, creating the table view with the data, and passing the information to the detail view.

The problem is i'm trying to load the remote HTML into the view using a variable but it will not display.

I've tried using this syntax:

```
<div [innerHTML]="data"></div>
```

I've tried using an iFrame, which works but then I can't interact with the links.

So my thought was to load the Ionic template data in the files themselves, and hopefully have them be clickable when the app loads.

For example:

```
<a href="#" (click)="pushPage('other.html')>click me</a>
```

And push that page onto the stack.

Any direction would be helpful and appreciated.

Comment: Ok thanks anyway..

Comment: using [innerHTML] should work. Are you sure you were passing valid html?

Comment: Is there any specific that should be omitted? Inline styles? Obviously just body content, etc.

Comment: As far as I know, I don't know of anything. I've read about people having trouble with it if they're trying to inject a really large block of html. Could you give an example of something similar to the html you're working with? Would make it much easier to find a solution.

Comment: I've decided to try out the Ionic Cloud service and drop the API integration all together, since my external stuff doesn't update often. But thanks for the help everyone.